# How to set a timeout on a request with Apollo-Client

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a React-Native app where I make requests to a GraphQL server. Everything works fine except I need a way to set the timeout on the request/client to 5 or 10 seconds. Currently the request takes a very long time before it times out (around 1 minute).

Here's a quick example of how I use the client.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: `${config.server_hostname}/graphql`
  })
});

client.query({ query: gqlString });
```

I have been unable to find any solution through StackOverflow, google search or Apollo's documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The Apollo client uses ([v1.9](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/v1.9.0/src/transport/networkInterface.ts#L186) and [apollo-link-http](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts#L169)) the fetch API to send the requests. Therefore there [is no cross-browser way to abort a fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Aborting_a_fetch). You could create you own Networkinterface or Link and use something like this:

```
const oldfetch = fetch;
fetch = function(input, opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(reject, opts.timeout);
      oldfetch(input, opts).then(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

But be careful as this doesn't actually abort the request. You can end up with a lot running requests and hit a browser limit.

BTW it looks like apollo-link-http [is prepared](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts#L191) for the [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) ;-)

Comment: Any idea if `AbortController` is operational yet?

Comment: Mozilla docs say it has full or partial support on most browsers now, but I'm thinking of using a polyfill just in case (https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill), to impement the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and used the following from [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-timeout). You can now control how long a request can wait before being aborted:

```js
import ApolloLinkTimeout from 'apollo-link-timeout';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

...

const timeoutLink = new ApolloLinkTimeout(10000); // 10 second timeout

const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: "/graphql" });

const timeoutHttpLink = timeoutLink.concat(httpLink);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({ link: timeoutHttpLink });

// use timeout-enabled Apollo client...

// Override timeout from any query 
<Query
 query={SOME_QUERY}
 variables={{
    someVar1: "foo",
    someVar2: "bar",
   }}
  context={{ timeout: 3000 }}
>
// ...
```

Comment: How is `apollo-link-timeout` considered "official" in any way? And how does this link do it?

Comment: Well, to be correct the word "official" is removed :-)

Comment: With help of this library. Can we implement it for each API or operation or its common for all the API requests?